# How can I standardize Japanese so I can do a word check for prohibited words in Lua?

Tags: unicode, lua, cpu-word, cjk

There are too many combinations of half-width, full-width, katakana, hiragana, kanji, and using substitute characters (eg そ instead of ん).

Python has a package called [jcconv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jcconv/0.1.2) which would help me do what I need to do. I want to convert strings into a standard form so I can go down my restricted word list.

Is this possible in Lua?

Comment: What makes a word prohibited?  What's the meaning of this?

Comment: You could start by converting the text from Unicode NFC to NFKC. That should take care of a lot of equivalences, like halfwidth vs. fullwidth, decomposed forms, and so on. It won't help you with cubstitutions like そ for ん or things like that (people really do that? Those 2 characters don't sound the same at all!)

Comment: When written in katakana, ソ and ン look alike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to convert strings between hiragana, katakana and half width katakana you could store the respective alphabet characters in different tables, and add a mapping between them (either by index or by key).

This is how jcconv is doing this too, judging by the source ([link](https://github.com/taichino/jcconv/blob/master/jcconv/jcconv.py)).

For example, if you want to convert hiragana to katakana you could do like this:

- set up a table where each element is defined as `[hiragana] = katakana`.
- iterate the string character by character and substitute if it is the case (I found a little library that does exactly this: [utf8.lua](https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/awesompd/blob/master/utf8.lua) provides a substitution function which accepts a mapping table).